# 2 JSON Schema Questions, Is the type keyword required and what is the differencen between Core and Validation

Tags: validation, schema, jsonschema

Okay I have been UP and DOWN the internet and I cannot find an answer that DEFINITIVELY answers the following question.

"Is the type keyword required?" If it is not then can some one, for all that is holy, please, in EXCRUCIATING detail, describe what should happen when it is not provided, validation-wise.

I have found this...

http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.1

But I have found so many other examples where a schema object can be defined and not have this keyword.

For example I have found this repo with testing examples.

https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/blob/master/tests/draft7/additionalProperties.json

Here they have a schema at line 5. It does not have a type but does look like they are talking about an object. Also on lines 21 - 25 they describe a test where an array is valid.

Can someone please clarify this for me.

Also for the second one,... What is the difference between the Core and the Validation as defined here...

https://json-schema.org/specification.html

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.  Is the `type` keyword required?

No.  Keywords will respond to instances of the types they're designed for, otherwise they will be ignored (silently pass validation).  So

```json
{ "minimum": 5 }
```

will pass *anything* as long as it's not a number less than 5.  Objects, strings, arrays, etc., all pass.  But as soon as you introduce a number, this keyword becomes interested and it'll do its thing.

Every keyword has a type or set of types that it responds to. `type` is one of the ones that responds to all of them.

#### 2. What are the different specs for?

We (the spec authors) thought it would make things a little simpler if we split the specification into two parts: one for the schema construction keywords (e.g. `$id`, `$schema`, `allOf`, `properties`, etc.), and one for value validation and annotation (e.g. `minimum`, `minLength`, etc.).  It *does* mean that you have to look into several documents in order to create a validator, however.

It also allows us to revise one of them without the other, though we've never done that.

This split was done several iterations ago, and we've just kept it as it seems to work well.

Comment: It's important to remember, JSON Schema is a constraints based vocabulary, not a data definition language. It's not like defining a table in a database, but rather defining additional constraints ON an existing table.

Comment: Additionally, the split allows future vocabularies and dialects to not use validation aspects if they aren't required to do any validation.